# AWS X-Ray Daemon | OpenTelemetry

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, open-telemetry, aws-xray

Is there a way for Opentelemetry Instrumentation to send traces to an AWS X-Ray Daemon and that daemon will export it to the central collector? Because both the agent collector and central collector are in the same region. When the application with the agent collector is invoked, it will go directly to the x-ray. So the traces are generated by the X service, not by the OpenTelemetry instrumentation.

If there is a way, how can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ADOT collector](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/collector) and configure receiver (e.g. OTEL and X-Ray) and exporters (e.g. OTEL and X-Ray), which will fit your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to drain the traces? What I mean, is to get only the full traces if I'm doing it end to end. Because I'm getting a bunch of traces.

`Service A -> Service B -> Service C...`

Instead of getting only the parent trace, which is Service A that has the underlying traces. I'm getting all of them. Also, I want to keep the metadata and the exceptions on the trace parent.